# "Snap" or warp image to be a perfect rectangle in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an image layer that's almost a perfect rectangle - it is a photograph I took of a rectangular object and have carefully cropped out.

Is there a way to either warp it into a perfect rectangle or have it snap to guidelines within my project? I want all of the edges to be perfectly straight and square.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Perspective Crop in Photoshop…
[click & hold on the Crop Tool, it's second down; or Shift C will cycle if you have that set in prefs]

[image]

Before… (*'scuse the "fine art"*;)

[image]

During…

[image]

After…

[image]

It will square things up nicely, but of course cannot fix the quality of my photography ;))
There's no snap, btw, just zoom the image until you can pick the 'perfect' corners.

Comment: Thanks for that! What if my layer is already fully cropped/isolated? It is an almost perfect rectangle layer and I'm trying to snap it and warp to my guidelines that are forming a rectangle

Comment: If it's not a perfect rectangle it cannot by definition be fully cropped. There's no snap in this, there's careful manual tweaking.

Comment: "warp to my guidelines": make a rectangular selection; right-click > free transform; right-click > distort